# How to create a flag animation in Flutter?

Tags: animation, flutter, pixel, flutter-animation

I am looking for a way to do something like this in Flutter:

[image]

The flag itself could be any widget, not only an image.

I had this idea of using a sin function in combination with a stateful Widget, but I basically have 2 problems:

1. I don't know how to access each pixel of the Widget.
2. If I do have access to each pixel, I don't know how to change its elevation (I know I can change the elevation of an entire Widget, but how do I do this in only part of a Widget?).

If I could solve these 2 points then I think I can try to elevate each pixel (and also change its color a bit) according to the output of a sin wave function and replicate the above effect.

Does anybody have any idea if something like this is possible in Flutter? Can anyone point me to the right direction to achieve such an effect?

Comment: Have a look at Rive and this https://pub.dev/packages/flare_flutter Maybe you can create an animation

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but Rive does not do what I want. I want to be able to run the above animation on any widget. I've been trying to find how I can "control every pixel" as the Flutter team is selling, but so far I am without luck :(